# sqrtf function alternative in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc

I am writing a project in Visual Studio then I use GCC in order to compile it. Sometimes it causes some problems: This time I cannot use sqrtf function because VS accepts it however GCC does not. So I need to find some way (maybe mathematical approach to calculate square root) to find square root of some number in a way both GCC and VS will accept. To be more precise this is the line which causes a problem:

```
float x_f = circleRadius - sqrtf((float)((circleRadius * circleRadius) - (y * y)));
```

I need to find the square root of (circleRadius^2 - y^2)

Comment: `To be more precise this is the line which causes a problem` which one? Linker error? Syntax error?

Comment: Have you tried std::sqrt? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt

Comment: Please provide details. `sqrtf` is definitely provided by all compilers.

Comment: Please provide a [repro] of the issue. `sqrtf` is certainly available, at least since C++11. Also note that the explicit cast is redundant. `std::sqrtf` already casts the argument to `float` implicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::sqrt` solves this problem:

```
#include <cmath>

auto foo(int circleRadius, int y) {
    float x_f = circleRadius - std::sqrt((float)(circleRadius * circleRadius - y * y));
}
```

compiles for both msvc and gcc according to https://godbolt.org/z/g9MJH6

You should prefer `std::sqrt` to `sqrtf` in C++. It works with more types, i.e., you could write your function more generically. It also does not use hungarian notation.

Edit: If you do not care if the calculation returns a float or a double, you could omit the cast and write the following:

```
auto x_f = circleRadius - std::sqrt(circleRadius * circleRadius - y * y);
```

If you care that a float is used, you can use `std::sqrtf` instead. 
If you have to use a cast, you should generally prefer `static_cast` to C-style casts. Reasons for this are listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used).

Comment: Note though that this would work with `std::sqrtf` just as well. OP's error lies probably in using wrong includes, forgetting the `std::` prefix or compiling against pre-C++11.

Answer (score 0):

Your situation may be if you use newer compiler at VC and older compiler at gcc.

Try to use sqrt or sqrtf WITH

```
#include <math.h>
```

Don't use

```
#include <cmath>
```

math.h should have sqrt, sqrtf definitions for both compilers.

Comment: I don't think that is a good suggestion. Rather, I would suggest always using `#include<cmath>` and using `std::sqrtf` instead. That would be much more consistent with the rest of the standard library.